# Handling certificates for establishing connection to Oracle using the go-ora driver

Tags: oracle, go, ssl, tls1.2

We can establish an SSL-based connection to the Oracle using go-ora driver, by including the SSL and SSL verify in the connection string.
But should certificate handling be included to the code?
For example, mysql has "RegisterTLSConfig" and mongoDB has "SetTLSConfig".
What does oracle have in similar to the above?

I have tried using RegisterTLSConfig but it is undefined for go-ora driver.

Answer (score 2):

Use an Oracle Wallet.

`go_ora` contains the [`NewWallet` function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sijms/go-ora#NewWallet) to:

> create new wallet object from file path

From the [Oracle Wallet Manager documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbimi/using-oracle-wallet-manager.html#GUID-E3E16C82-E174-4814-98D5-EADF1BCB3C37):

> #### 6.1.1 What Is Oracle Wallet Manager?
>
> You can use Oracle Wallet Manager to manage public key security credentials on Oracle clients and servers. The wallets it creates can be read by Oracle Database, Oracle Application Server, and the Oracle Identity Management infrastructure.
>
> Oracle Wallet Manager enables wallet owners to manage and edit the security credentials in their Oracle wallets. A wallet is a password-protected container used to store authentication and signing credentials, including private keys, certificates, and trusted certificates needed by SSL. You can use Oracle Wallet Manager to perform the following tasks:

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know whether it is possible to establish SSL connection to Oracle without using wallet?  If not,  I will have to create a new wallet.

Comment: Also do you know how to add certificate once new wallet is created using the NewWallet function